# LoadError issue with JRuby and NetBeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, jruby

- I am using netBeans with JRuby 1.5.1
- I tried to install a gem but I got permission issues.

  - I solved it by changing user access.
- Then I get this error [[link]](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5581) while trying to install gem again.
- I installed JRuby 1.7.4 and could manage to install all gems there
- Now the problem is when I run the project I get this error:

  LoadError: no such file to load -- initializer
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054